# How add Placeholder to login form

Tags: forms

I need to add *Placeholder* property to Drupal 7 login form from template.php. Not to use a module. and also want to know how to add other attributes like *Required* etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it cannot be done unless using the module. You can try like this

1) Adding the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter in the module to add placeholders, required and some other form attributes.

2) In the template file you can call that form using drupal_get_form('form-id', args1, args2, etc..)

3) Finally, pass the form to the tpl file.

Example:

1) In .module

```
function yourModule_form_user_login_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['name']['#attributes'] = array(
    'placeholder' => array (
       t('Username')
     )
  );
  $form['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
  /* Add other attributes like this*/
}
```

2) In template.php

```
$variables['login_form'] = drupal_get_form('user_login');
```

3) In .tpl.php

```
<?php print render($login_form); ?>
```

I hope this will work !!

Comment: Thanks for your help it's working in template.php. I will also try them in module and .tpl.

Comment: This worked in drupal 8 too.